# Ramda.js: Arguments to list

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Trying to figure out Ramda here. Does Ramda have a method to turn arguments to a list? E.g:

```
R.argumentsToList(1)(2) => [1, 2]
```

The problem that I'm actually facing is that my function is passed 2 arguments and I need to work with both arguments, yet `R.compose` only allows the rightmost function to work with multiple arguments. Turning my arguments to a list would allow me to bypass this - or would that be a bad approach?

**Practical problem:** I want to pass 2 strings into my function. Those should be turned into a merged object, e.g:

```
f('firstString', 'second') => {firstString: 'firstString', second: 'second'}
```

I know that I can use `R.merge` and `R.objOf`, but I don't know how to handle and work with the 2 arguments that are passed to the function.

Comment: `arguments` already is a sort of list. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Creating a `list` function is [one of the recipes](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#create-a-list-function) in the [Ramda Cookbook](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook).  It turns out to be fairly simple:

```
var list = R.unapply(R.identity);
list(1, 2, 3); // => [1, 2, 3]
```

This is based on the simple [`unapply`](http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/docs/#unapply), which converts a variadic function into one that accepts an array.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this with [`R.useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/docs/#useWith):

```
R.useWith(R.concat, [R.of, R.of])
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the easiest/best solution for this, because I'm very inexperienced. Maybe someone with more experience can share their knowledge?

Comment: This works, but only for two arguments.  The answer I just gave works for any number, and is somewhat simpler.  Nonetheless, nice job in coming up with this one!